# In PHP Class, calling interal method is showing error message

Tags: php

I am trying to lowercase all the keys of a multi-dimensional array using following function. Below code is from a class. I see that when I use this method `to_lower()` in a class then it's showing me error message:

> The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your
>   site admin email inbox for instructions.

But if I test this method/function without a class it's working good! Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
public function to_lower($arr)
{
    return array_map(function($item){
        if(is_array($item))
            $item = to_lower($item);
        return $item;
    },array_change_key_case($arr));
}

public function logout_redirect_to()
{

    $user = $this->current_user;
    $options = $this->options['wpll_general_settings'];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->to_lower($options)); // why this line is showing error message? 
    wp_die();
    /// more code here....
}
```

Comment: Activate error reporting and/or look at your error logs to get a detailed error message, not just the web server’s default error page.

Comment: @deceze I am checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call is wrong

```
public function to_lower($arr)
    {
        return array_map(function($item){
            if(is_array($item))
                $item = $this->to_lower($item); //Your recursive call is wrong
            return $item;
        },array_change_key_case($arr));
   }
```

For debugging help, display your php errors on local development server or use error_log to get details about the error :)